# Open a ViewController Login over JASidePanelController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, appdelegate

I just starting to develop in Objective-C / iOS and I'm trying to open a Login ViewController as my first ViewController. That's working fine:

[AppDelegate.m]

```
UPLoginViewController *login = [[UPLoginViewController alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = login;
```

The problem is when I try to open it over the JASidePanelController. I don't have any idea about how to make it. If I open first the JASidePanelController, I have to open the login into the viewDidLoad getting the delegate property from Login

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
UPLoginViewController *login = [[UPLoginViewController alloc] init];

login.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:login.view];
[self addChildViewController:login];
}
```

But doing this my LoginViewController open inside of the JASidePanelController (centerViewController).

What's the better way to open a LoginViewController over all, then open my JASidePanelController and get the parameters/delegate of my LoginViewController?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing a `[self presentViewController:login animated:YES completion:nil];` That will pop the view up modally over the entire view hierarchy.

Also, take a look at: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

and http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html